# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function when using mongoDB sort operator

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I try to get the document with the latest date, but I get this error: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function`.

My code:

```
console.log(Games.find({authorId: authorId}).sort( { releaseDate: -1 } ).limit(1)); // error
console.log(Games.find({authorId: authorId}).fetch()); // expected outpout
```

(The value `releaseDate` exists and is in `ISODate` format.)
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am using Meteor 0.9.2.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it!

```
Games.find({authorId: authorId}, { sort: { 'releaseDate' : -1 } , limit:1});
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as to what you did wrong before so future stackoverflowers can learn from it

Comment: @Huangism, since they are using Meteor the query, while similar, takes a slightly different syntax.